# How to create infinite loop, call method in it on if(condition=true), and continue infinite loop after execution of method also. in java?

Tags: java

I have a method RunFrame();

I want to call it in infinite loop.

```
while(true)
{
   if(x==true)
   { RunFrame(); }
}
```

If condition is true, After execution of method my loop gets break; i want to continue the loop again till next event of x again and so on..

Comment: It will never come out of the while loop unless there's some exception in RunFrame() method. What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: How is this not working already?

Comment: Is there something in RunFrame that stops the system entirely?

Comment: Or, x may be false. Check the code. RunFrame() may be changing the value of x too.

Comment: I want to create infinite loop. then get events of file monitoring using for loop inside it. and check if(event==requiredEvent) then call method RunFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will keep running indefinitely due to your `while(true)` clause, regardless of what value `x` has (since `x` only dictates when `RunFrame()` gets called).

The only issue I see is that `RunFrame` throws some sort of exception or aborts the program. You can try it like below:

```
while(true)
{
   if(x==true)
   { 
       try
       {
           RunFrame(); 
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

The above should cater for exceptions.

EDIT:

Seeing your comment:

> I want to create infinite loop. then get events of file monitoring
>   using for loop inside it. and check if(event==requiredEvent) then call
>   method RunFrame.

You can take a look at the [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) which will allow you to `watch` a given directory. You can take a look at [this Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) to see how you can achieve what you want. This will fire events which you will then handle, without the need of your code having to keep on looping indefinitely.